# How to get all values that matches with an array of values?

Tags: mysql

I have more than one filter on my `MySQL` query. It will retrieve the information from a user depending on some filters.

The filters are selected by the users so they can filter by more than one value. All of them are unique except one of the filters than can return more than one row in the subquery.

What the user can filter:

- By Name
- By Nationality of the user

Taking in consideration that `Name` is unique in this case but there can be more than one user that has the same nationality. Also, if there is not any filter the query should return all `UserInfo` from all users.

Also, the problem that I am facing is that the information is stored in two different tables. This is the structure:

```
UserInformation                   Users
----------------                ----------                          
ID                               ID
Name                             UserInfo
Nationality
```

So I have to get the `UserInfo` of the user(s) that matches with the corresponding filters. If I do the filter by `Name` I do not have any problems because it can only be unique but it gives me an error if I use `Nationality` as a filter.

Both tables are connected by ID.

What I do by the moment is:

```
SELECT UserInfo FROM Users WHERE 
     ID LIKE (SELECT ID FROM UserInformation WHERE Name='UniqueName') AND 
     ID LIKE (SELECT ID FROM UserInformation WHERE Nationality='Spanish')
```

Of course, I can see that there is a problem if I try to filter by `Nationality` if there is more than one value that matches with that `Nationality` because they will not be able to make the filter with more than one returned `ID`.

I have to notice that I cannot modify the structure of the tables because I do not have enough permissions and I just can consult them.

But then, how can I retrieve the `UserInfo` of all users that matches with one, two or neither filters (in which case it will return all `UserInfo` values)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the tables:

```
SELECT UserInfo FROM Users
JOIN UserInformation ON Users.ID = UserInformation.ID
WHERE Name='UniqueName' 
AND Nationality='Spanish'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
SELECT UserInfo FROM Users WHERE 
 ID IN ((SELECT ID FROM UserInformation WHERE Name='UniqueName') OR
  (SELECT ID FROM UserInformation WHERE Nationality='Spanish') OR
  (SELECT ID FROM UserInformation WHERE Nationality='Spanish' AND Name='UniqueName'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view which contains relevant columns from both the tables. This will help you look for records at one place.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "[Your_Schema]"."USERDETAILS" ("ID", "NAME", "NATIONALITY", "USERINFO") AS 
  SELECT T1.ID,
   T1.NAME,
   T1.NATIONALITY,
   T2.USERINFO,
FROM   USERINFORMATION T1, USERS T2
WHERE T2.ID= T1.ID;
```

Then you can just fire a **select** query to fetch the required records.

```
SELECT USERINFO FROM USERDETAILS WHERE NAME='UniqueName' and Nationality='Spanish';
```

*Constraint: You need to have permissions to create the view. At times Table Structure modifications rights are not granted but you might be allowed to create views.*